# Displaying point cloud in browser

Tags: ros, ros3djs, ros-hydro, rosbridge, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been looking into displaying a point cloud in the browser using ros3djs and rosbridge. There's a tutorial for streaming point cloud data from a Kinect, but I just want to take a pointcloud2 message and render it with ros3djs. As documented, it seems like it can only take a stream directly from a camera, but is there a way within the current framework to just display directly from a pointcloud2 message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172895/displaying-point-cloud-in-browser/) by [jdreic](https://answers.ros.org/users/18796/jdreic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This must be the tutorial you're talking about (I've only ever seen one)

http://wiki.ros.org/ros3djs/Tutorials/Point%20Cloud%20Streaming%20from%20a%20Kinect

If your point cloud is coming from a topic then that's all you need. The reason this is easy with a camera is because the point cloud sources, nodes, and topics already written and work.

That being said, the PointCloud2 topic over rosbridge websocket is wonky as of indigo, good luck with that..

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can create a temporary topic subscription and call the processMessage function of ROS3D.PointCloud2 class.
In the below code call the displayCloud function with your sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 message.

```
var viewer = new ROS3D.Viewer({
  divID : 'webViewer',
  width : 800,
  height : 600,
  antialias : true,
  background : '#111111'
});
var tmpSub = new ROS3D.PointCloud2({
   ros:ros,
   tfClient: tfClient, 
   rootObject: viewer.scene,
   topic: '/tmp/points',
   material: {size: 0.01, color: 0xeeeeee }
});
function displayCloud(msg){
  tmpSub.processMessage(msg);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [sharath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30227/sharath/) with karma: 31 on 2018-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roua](https://answers.ros.org/users/55583/roua/) on 2020-06-07**:
did this work for you ?

**Comment by [sharath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30227/sharath/) on 2020-06-08**:
Yeah, it works!

**Comment by [Bender_From_Futurama](https://answers.ros.org/users/82310/bender_from_futurama/) on 2021-09-09**:
How is the latency using this? And how is the bandwidth requirements? Is there some kind of compression?

**Comment by [Bender_From_Futurama](https://answers.ros.org/users/82310/bender_from_futurama/) on 2021-09-14**:
How do you decode the point cloud from roslibjs to get the raw data?